# does opendatakit provide convertion of html from Xfrom

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I found this link from open data kit- https://opendatakit.org/xlsform/.  This will take .xls sheet as input which is a representation of html forms which I prepared using this http://xlsform.org/en/.

This opendatakit gives me an .XML file.  I can also view a preview.  But I do not know how they convert XML into web browser supported scripts like html.

Basically I want to make html forms using xls sheet.